# Spring boot custom validator

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Использую Spring Boot MVC

```
@Component
public class VehicleMakeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<VehicleMakeUniqueField, String> {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleMakeRepository vehicleMakeRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(VehicleMakeUniqueField constraint) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && vehicleMakeRepository.findByTitle(value).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Репозиторий

```
public interface VehicleMakeRepository extends CrudRepository<VehicleMake, Long> {
    Optional<VehicleMake> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

в контроллере

```
@RequestMapping(path = "...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createOrUpdateVct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("vm") VehicleMake vm, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors())
            return "category/add-edit-vehicle-make";
        if (vm.getId() == null) {
            vehicleMakeRepository.save(vm);
        } 
}
```

Когда проходит валидацию, все ок.
Когда уходит на `vehicleMakeRepository.save(vm);` в VehicleMakeValidator в ссылке vehicleMakeRepository - null...

Не понимаю почему там пусто и как Hibernat'у положить туда ссылку на его же репозиторий?

Comment: Вас не смущает, что Вы сохраняете в БД vm, айди которого null?

Comment: нет не смущает.